# Need help got stuck in javascript date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
var d = "02-12-2016";
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: d,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy';
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> <input type="text" id="final"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello friends i am using this var d="02-12-2016" and i want to show a next date in a text field which is in front of date picker and that text box will have a date 02-15-2016

I am working on it and i am not getting any way how it will be done.

Comment: Change it to: `var d = "2016/12/02";`. The format is `YYYY/MM/DD`.

Comment: How its going to be possible after changing date format

Comment: The reason is, JavaScript understands the Date that way, if not it says invalid date.

Comment: Its not working i just tried and its closing dates till 2021

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use ISO format for date operations:

```
var d = "2016-02-12";
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: d,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(date) {
      $("#final").val(secondDate(date));
    }
  });
});

function secondDate(date) {

  var d = new Date(date);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);

  var month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
  var day = '' + d.getDate();
  var year = d.getFullYear();

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

Comment: Its showing my selected date in a final textbox but i need a final date to be 3 dates after the date i select

Answer (score 0):

according to api doc : [jquery-ui-1.11](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) it work either.

```
minDate: d,
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
defaultDate: d,
altField: '#final'
```